How to create grid size 2*2 that have border that take all the cell?
I try to create grid - size 2x2 that each cell will hold border like in the picture.
I want that the border will be on maximum size of each cell on this grid.
how to do it ?
( I don't want to put size of the border hard code )


According to your requirement, you can define it like below:
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Stroke="Aqua" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 40" Margin="25,25">
           
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Aqua" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 40" Margin="25,25">

        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Stroke="Aqua" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 40" Margin="25,25">

        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Aqua" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 40" Margin="25, 25">

        </Border>
</Grid>



this not work - i try it already before i publish the question

@Yanshof make the Margin="0"

how Margin = 0 will help ?
i don't undestand

@Yanshof You can see my running output, it does work. If not, please help create a Minimal, Reproducible Example and add it to your post. Thx!
